# How to pass an array to a C function via LLVM?

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I'm trying to create an array with two elements of size 64 bits. Once the array is created, it is stored in a local variable. The local variable is then loaded to send the values to a C function.

The LLVM bytecode:

```
define i32 @main() {
  %1 = alloca [2 x i64], align 8
  store [2 x i64] [i64 1, i64 10], [2 x i64]* %1, align 4
  %2 = load [2 x i64], [2 x i64]* %1, align 4
  call void @printType([2 x i64] %2)
  ret i32 0
}
```

The C code:

```
void printType(int64_t* parts) {
   printf("%ld\n", parts[0]);
}
```

The above function crashes. However, the following function does not:

```
void printType(int64_t parts) {
    printf("%ld\n", parts);
}
```

This prints the first element. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be an alignment problem. You have attempted to store an i64 (8 bytes) with an alignment of 4. To fix this simply change every instance of 'align 4' with 'align 8'.

The reason why your first example fails is that you have aligned 'parts' to 4bytes. So when you dereference it e.g. `parts[0]` you are attempting to access unaligned memory, which depending on your architecture/OS may result in a segmentation fault or other error. Some systems will allow unaligned access, others will not. It's also worth noting that in some cases a 4byte aligned value will also be 8byte aligned, so in some cases your first version `printType` will work.

So I believe this should work;

```
define i32 @main() {
  %1 = alloca [2 x i64], align 8
  store [2 x i64] [i64 1, i64 10], [2 x i64]* %1, align 8
  %2 = load [2 x i64], [2 x i64]* %1, align 8
  call void @printType([2 x i64] %2)
  ret i32 0
}
```

Your second pass-by value version of `printType` is implicitly aligned to 8bytes by the compiler. Which is why it doesn't crash.